# .well-known/acme-challenge/xxxx gives 404 nginx

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I manage a wordpress site.
I have below code block in my nginx config file.

```
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    proxy_read_timeout 3000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
    proxy_send_timeout 3000;
    expires 1s;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and URLs with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache URIs containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php
                         |sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged-in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass
        |wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
   location / {
        autoindex on;
        client_max_body_size 1000M;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires 1s;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        expires 1s;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        default_type "text/plain";
        try_files $uri =404;
   }
}
```

I created `test` file in `/var/www/wordpress/.well-known/acme-challenge/` folder.

when I load `https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge` it gives me `nice 404 from wordpress`.

when I load `https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/` it gives me below error

```
404 Not Found
 nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

when I try to load `https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test` also it gives me. below 404 error.

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Because of this my ssl renew fails.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Where is `.well-known/acme-challenge/test`? Nginx will be looking for it at `/var/www/wordpress/.well-known/acme-challenge/test`

Comment: @RichardSmith it is available at this location /var/www/wordpress/.well-known/acme-challenge/test

Comment: @AMendis There should be some corresponding line in the nginx error log, something like `open() "/var/www/wordpress/.well-known/acme-challenge/test" failed (2: No such file or directory)`, can you check your nginx error log for it?